# Sinon not stubbing on module.exports

Tags: node.js, sinon

If create an file with the following contents

```
const validateEmail = email => {
    sendEmail(email);
};

const sendEmail = email => {
  return true;
};

module.exports = {
  validateEmail,
  sendEmail,
};
```

And a test that tries to stub out the second function...

```
it('Should call sendEmail if a valid email is passed', () => {
  let sendEmailSpy = sinon.stub(checkEmail, 'sendEmail');
  checkEmail.validateEmail('acorrectemail@therightformat.com');
  assert.isTrue(sendEmailSpy.called);
});
```

It still calls the `sendEmail` function and the test fails

However, if I write the `module.exports` like this:

```
module.exports = {
  validateEmail(email) {
      this.sendEmail(email);
  },
  sendEmail(email) {
    return true;
  },
};
```

It stubs it correctly...Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer - context

Long answer - in the first scenario, the exported `sendEmail` function **is not** the same as the internal one that is used by `validateEmail`. The exported function becomes a new property of the object being exported and simply references the internal one.

In the second scenario, you explicitly reference the `sendEmail` function on the exported object (i.e. `this.sendEmail(...)`) from `validateEmail` therefore it will use the stubbed version.

Moral of the story - you can't stub something you can't see.

Comment: Riiight ok. Is there a way of stubbing using the first scenario?

Comment: @OmisNomis not based on your current implementation no, it needs to be externally accessible in order to stub it. What's wrong with the second approach?